# Automapper automatic mapping

Tags: automapper, dto

I have a Domain model that countains the following properties :

```
public class Profile
{
    public DateTime birthDate { get; set; }
    public List<Language> languages { get; set; }
}
```

Where Language represent an enumeration defined here :

```
public enum Language
{
    English,
    French,
    Spannish
}
```

i would like to automatically populate the two following properties based on the languages values stored inside my domain model :

```
public Dictionary <int, String> languages_list { get; set; }
public List<string> languages_known { get; set; }
```

the question is : can it be done using automapper , if so how should i proceed ?

Comment: Can you add some more detail? ie, what are you expecting to see populated in each property (eg, what does the `int` represent in the `dictionary`?). Ideally a unit test that contains example data would be great.

Comment: the int must represent the index in the enumeration for example ( for English it's 1) the string represents the value , here it's english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, using the detail you've provided this is what I've come up with.

**Classes**

```cs
public class SOProfile
{
    public DateTime birthDate { get; set; }
    public List<Language> languages { get; set; }
}

public class WhatAmI
{
    public Dictionary<int, String> languages_list { get; set; }
    public List<string> languages_known { get; set; }
}
```

Note that `Profile` was renamed to `SOProfile` to avoid a clash with `AutoMapper`

**AutoMapper Configuration**

```cs
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get
        {
            return "MyProfile";
        }
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<SOProfile, WhatAmI>()
              .ForMember(dest => dest.languages_list,
                         opt => opt.MapFrom(
                             src => src.languages
                                 .Select((x,i) => new { Item = x, Index = i})
                                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Index,
                                               x => x.Item.ToString())))
              .ForMember(dest => dest.languages_known,
                         opt => opt.MapFrom(
                             src => src.languages
                                 .Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList()));
    }
}
```

**Unit Tests**

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class MappingTests
{
    [Test]
    public void AutoMapper_Configuration_IsValid()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(m => m.AddProfile<MyProfile>());
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }

    [Test]
    public void AutoMapper_Mapping_IsValid()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(m => m.AddProfile<MyProfile>());
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        var profile = new SOProfile
            {
                birthDate = new DateTime(2012, 01, 01),
                languages = new List<Language>
                    {
                        Language.English,
                        Language.French,
                        Language.English,
                        Language.French
                    }
            };

        var rc = Mapper.Map<SOProfile, WhatAmI>(profile);

        Assert.That(rc, Is.Not.Null);

        Assert.That(rc.languages_known, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(rc.languages_known.Count, Is.EqualTo(4));

        Assert.That(rc.languages_known.Count(x => x == "English"),
                    Is.EqualTo(2));
        Assert.That(rc.languages_known.Count(x => x == "French"),
                    Is.EqualTo(2));
        Assert.That(rc.languages_known.Count(x => x == "Spanish"),
                    Is.EqualTo(0));

        Assert.That(rc.languages_list, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(rc.languages_list.Count, Is.EqualTo(4));

        Assert.That(rc.languages_list.First(x => x.Key == 0).Value,
                    Is.EqualTo("English"));
        Assert.That(rc.languages_list.First(x => x.Key == 1).Value,
                    Is.EqualTo("French"));
        Assert.That(rc.languages_list.First(x => x.Key == 2).Value,
                    Is.EqualTo("English"));
        Assert.That(rc.languages_list.First(x => x.Key == 3).Value,
                    Is.EqualTo("French"));
    }
}
```